# Entity Framework connect to mutiple database at runtime

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, architecture, entity-framework-4

I want to ask if I had a proper design. 
 **Background:**
I develop my web application with EF4. The application will be used by three offices. The business processes in the three offices is similar with each other. Each office has the database their own, but most tables, SPROCs in the databases are the same.
**My thinking:**
I want to extract the same tables and stored procedure to a single edmx file, and point the connection string to database at runtime basing on the logon user.

I add a method to the constructor

```
MPREntities(string connectionString, string containerName)
```

And will pass the connectionString and the container name, when initializing the **MPREntities**. The containerName is the same - "MPREntities", it does not depend on the databases pointed to. The connectionString will be changed according to the logon user  before passing in. I have done some testing and seems it works. But is that a normal approach? any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That approach will work, and is a good use case for this.

Comment: The system go live last month. Up to now it works well. The advantage is no need to maintain lots of similar models generated via database. The disadvantage is I need to keep the databases constant.

Comment: Glad it works, yes keeping the databases consistent is important for this approach to be effective, however that can be considered an advantage rather than a disadvantage. 
Without this 'forcing factor' your databases will tend to diverge over time. You can also set up multiple models per database, so if you wanted to facilitate differences, use this model as your 'common' model, and another database specific 'extension' model